# Android contacts provider [Read,Update,Delete]

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I'm studying only recently Android.
I do not know if it's me, but I do not understand the Android sudio documentation regarding the contacts, I tried reading the few guides about it, and other articles, but I could not understand how it works.
Now I am only able to read some contacts and their information, but without being able to modify and delete them.
My purpose is to create a synchronization of contacts service.
The data to whom they are interested are: Name Number (Home, Work, Mobile, Mail).
If no one knows how to read the data correctly, edit, delete and create them would be very grateful, perhaps with a sample code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the information from below link.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html